# Understanding how to use simple objects in c++

Tags: c++, object, output

I have this following code that I must follow:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class T {
public:
    T() {}
};

class S {
public:
    static int i;
    S()    { i++; }
    S(int unused) { i += 2; }
    S(T unused)   { i += 3; }
};

int S::i = 0;

S f(S unused)
{
    return 0;
}

S g(S& unused)
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << S::i << "\n";
    S s1, s2(2);
    cout << S::i << "\n";
    T t;
    cout << S::i << "\n";
    S s3(t);
    cout << S::i << "\n";
    f(t);
    cout << S::i << "\n";
    g(s1);
    cout << S::i << "\n";
}
```

From following every declaration and instantiation in the main method, I can follow the output as follows:

0
3
3
6
6
6

I am correct until:
0
3
3
6

But the last two numbers that will be outputted are:
11
13

I am unsure what exactly f(t) and g(s1) do? I am unable to follow how they are changing the value of i.
What do these two statements do?

Answer (score 2):

Both `f()` and `g()` are declared to return a value of type `S` but they actually do a `return` with an integer value.

So what actually happens is that a temporary value of type `S` is automatically created from the integer using the *conversion constructor*  `S(int unused)`. That function increments `S::i` by 2.

Also `f()` takes as argument a value of type `S`, but it is calld with a value of type `T`. Hence, a temporary value of type `S` is automatically created by the compiler, using the *conversion constructor* `S(T unused)`. That function increments `S::i` by 3.